# Does python functools.singledispatch work with Generator type?

Tags: python, functools, single-dispatch

I extended the example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch by adding a registration for generator type

```py
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import Generator

@singledispatch
def fun(arg, verbose):
    if verbose:
        print("Let me just say,", end=" ")
    print(arg)

@fun.register
def _(arg: list, verbose):
    if verbose:
        print("Enumerate this:")
    for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
        print(i, elem)

# NEW CODE BELOW

@fun.register
def _(arg: Generator, verbose):
    if verbose:
        print("Enumerate this:")
    for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
        print(i, elem)

fun([3,4,5], verbose=True)
fun((i for i in range(6, 10)), verbose=True)
```

while it works with list, it doesn't seem to work with generator with error like

```
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid annotation for 'arg'. typing.Generator is not a class.
```

Is it expected that `singledispatch` does not work with generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typing.Generator` is a type hint, not a type. You need `types.GeneratorType`.

```
from types import GeneratorType

@fun.register
def _(arg: GeneratorType, verbose):
    if verbose:
        print("Enumerate this:")
    for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
        print(i, elem)
```

Objects are not considered instances of type hints according to `isinstance`, which is what `singledispatch` uses to decide which function to use for a given argument. With this change, you'll get the expected output

```
$ python3 tmp.py
Enumerate this:
0 3
1 4
2 5
Enumerate this:
0 6
1 7
2 8
3 9
```